# Stripe, PHP api Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe gateway with their latest php api:

```
      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
      try {

        //Create a token
        $token = \Stripe\Token::create(array("card" => array(
                "name" => Client Name",
                "number" => 4242424242424242,
                "exp_month" => 12,
                "exp_year" => 2018,
                "cvc" => 123,
                )));

        //Create a client
        $client = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            "description" => "John Doe",
            "source" => $token['id'],
            ));

        //Charge client
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => round(1.99 * 100, 0),
            "currency" => "USD",
            "customer" => $client['id'],
            "description" => "Membership Access"
            ));

      }
      catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
           $e->getJsonBody();
      }
```

Everything works fine, Client gets created in my stripe dashboard, and charge is there as well, but I keep getting Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in \lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php on line 292

Comment: Try creating an issue about it here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php since it's not being handled by a proper exception.

Comment: look here: https://github.com/haimiz/laravel-cashier-stripe

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by passing an object as the `customer` parameter, rather than a string ID.